# How to use an ArcGIS Server globe service on the web?

Tags: arcgis-server, web-mapping, 3d-analyst, arcglobe

I created an ArcGlobe document containing a 3D multipatch building...

[image]

... then published this to ArcGIS Server as a Globe Service. The help page [Displaying data from a globe service](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00q80000011n000000) says:

> Globe services can be consumed and displayed by the suite of ArcGIS
>   applications, including ArcGlobe, ArcCatalog, ArcReader, and ArcGIS
>   Explorer Desktop

but I can't see any mention of a web API or platform. What is the next step in order to use this globe service *in a web page*?

Comment: The landing page when you create a new app in the ArcGIS Web App Builder 1.1 says [coming soon](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7mYwW.jpg) next to 3D - this may imply that Esri do not currently have a 3D web viewer?

Comment: The [CityEngine web viewer](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/about-cityengine-web-viewer.htm) looks promising but it depends on a Web Scene created by exporting from ArcScene...

Comment: Version 4 of the JavaScript API will support 3D, although I can't find much on it on the web right now. At the 2015 Dev Summit they did some pretty sweet demos and presentations, although I cannot find any of those on the Esri video site.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds perfect. The story for 3D in Esri is currently a bit confusing (eg why does the ancient ArcScene allow exporting to CityEngine web viewer, but the newer ArcGlobe does not?). JSAPI support would be ideal.